# Xposed - Return class constructor

Tags: xposed

Decompilled method:

```
private static l c(String str, String str2, String str3, String str4) {
    l lVar;
    k kVar = (k) m.get(str);
    j jVar = (j) l.get(str);
    if (kVar != null) {
        lVar = new l(kVar, str2, str3);
    } else if (jVar != null) {
        lVar = new l(jVar, str2, str3);
    } else {
        lVar = new l(j.GENERIC, str2, str3);
    }
    lVar.a(str4);
    return lVar;
}
```

How to use Xposed to return new l (jVar, str2, str3) with its specific values?
The beginning of the code I have is:

```
    try {
        findAndHookMethod("com.xiaomi.hm.health.ui.smartplay.h", lpparam.classLoader, "c", String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, new XC_MethodHook() {
            @Override
            protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) {
                String pkg = (String) param.args[0];
                if (pkg == "com.perm.kate_new_6"){
                    return ???;
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `XC_MethodHook`'s `afterHookedMethod` method needs to return void. I.e., the return of the hooked method needs be be set via [setResult](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/blob/art/app/src/main/java/de/robv/android/xposed/XC_MethodHook.java#L96) method of `XC_MethodHook` instead.

Internally it sets `returnEarly` to `true` which is checked in [XposedBridge](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/blob/art/app/src/main/java/de/robv/android/xposed/XposedBridge.java#L358), preventing the original method code from executing, as well as any other hooks on the method.

If you just want to access whatever the method was originally going to return then [getResult()](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/blob/art/app/src/main/java/de/robv/android/xposed/XC_MethodHook.java#L87) should do.

If you need to return anything else, you can use reflection or Xposed's helpers ([findClass](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/blob/art/app/src/main/java/de/robv/android/xposed/XposedHelpers.java#L65)) to retrieve the l, k and j classes, replicate the code if needed, create a new instance and return it via `setResult`. Alternatively you can use a `XC_MethodReplacement` hook instead as you will likely replicate its functionality anyways.